# How to operate on list generator using numba

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to use a simple code that tries to use numba and list generator and I get an error executing the following code.

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def perform_search(simple_list, number):
    gen = (ind for ind in xrange(len(simple_list)) if simple_list[ind] != number)
    return next(gen)

x = [1,1,1,2,1,3]
perform_search(x, 1)
```

When I execute the above code I get a `ValueError`, however, when just use the decorator `@numba.jit`, I get a a `LoweringError`.

Please help me to perform this simple search using generator (or otherwise). Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, but you may want to ask on the mailing list or in the gitter chat: https://gitter.im/numba/numba

Comment: To be clear, what you've got here is called a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression), not a "list generator".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have

```
gen = (ind for ind in xrange(len(simple_list)) if simple_list[ind] != number)
```

is a generator expression, which is not supported by numba at the moment.

If you use square brackets instead, like:

```
gen = [ind for ind in xrange(len(simple_list)) if simple_list[ind] != number]
```

then it is a list-comprehension and numba can support it.  With that change, `gen` is a `list` and you can index it (i.e. `gen[0]`).

**EDITED:**

The following code is a suggestion from the user sklam in gitter, that I'm updating here.

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def the_gen(simple_list, number):
    for ind in range(len(simple_list)):
        if simple_list[ind] != number:
            yield ind


@numba.jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def perform_search(simple_list, number):
    for i in the_gen(simple_list, number):
        print(i)
```

If you do the above way, you will be able to do with a generator (so gains in memory and time) since generator-expression is currently not supported by `numba`.

Comment: Thanks @sklam . I'm currently using your solution already. However, as you can imagine, this alternative is memory (and time) intensive for large arrays.
Do you know when the generator is supported in numba?

Comment: Edited the response based on the help received from sklam over gitter.

Comment: Presumably, you could drop the generator entirely, and just have `perform_search` do `for ind, val in enumerate(simple_list):` `if val != number: return ind`? Keep the use of `xrange` if `numba` removes indexing overhead completely (also, was the second solution supposed to be `range` or `xrange`, if it's Py2, `range` involves creating a huge unnecessary list of all indices up front).

Comment: Yes, thanks @ShadowRanger, that helps. And, yes, it has to be xrange instead of range. Edited it.