# Delete a row in numpy.array in numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

It's my first time to post something here. I'm trying to delete a row inside a numpy array inside a numba jitclass. I wrote the following code to remove any row containing 3:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

>>> a

>>> array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

>>> i = np.where(a==3)

>>> i

>>> (array([0]), array([2]))
```

I cannot use numpy.delete() function since it is not supported by numba and cannot assign a None type vale to the row. All I could do is to assign 0's to the row by:

```
>>> a[i[0]] = 0

>>> a

>>> array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

But I want to remove the row completely.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you looked at the code for `np.delete`?  You shouldn't be trying to speed it up, or replicate it, without thoroughly understanding what it does.  Let me give you clue - makes a new array, and fills it with desired values from the old.

Comment: You mean the array element will not be in their original  locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact not an easy task, since numba has the following restrictions:

- no support for `np.delete`
- no support for the `axis` keyword in `np.all` and `np.any`
- no support for 2D array indexing (at least not with bool masks)
- no or hampered direct creation of bool masks with `np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.bool)` or similar functions

But still there are several approaches you can take to solve your problem. I tested a few and creating a boolean mask seems to be the fastest and cleanest way.

```
@nb.njit
def delete_workaround(arr, num):
    mask = np.zeros(arr.shape[0], dtype=np.int64) == 0
    mask[np.where(arr == num)[0]] = False
    return arr[mask]

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

delete_workaround(a, 3)
```

This solution also has the **huge advantage of preserving your array dimensions**, even when only one row or an empty array is returned. This is **important for jitclasses**, since jitclasses rely heavily on fixed dimensions.

Since you request it, I'll show you a solution which converts arrays to lists and back. Since reflected lists are not yet supported with all python methodsin numba, you'll have to use a wrapper for some parts of the function:

```
@nb.njit
def delete_lrow(arr_list, num):
    idx_list = []
    for i in range(len(arr_list)):
        if (arr_list[i] != num).all():
            idx_list.append(i)
    res_list = [arr_list[i] for i in idx_list]
    return res_list

def wrap_list_del(arr, num):
    arr_list = list(arr)
    return np.array(delete_lrow(arr_list, num))

arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[10,11,5,13],[10,11,3,13],[10,11,99,13]])
arr2 = np.random.randint(0, 256, 100000*4).reshape(-1, 4)

%timeit delete_workaround(arr, 3)
# 1.36 µs ± 128 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit wrap_list_del(arr, 3)    
# 69.3 µs ± 4.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit delete_workaround(arr2, 3)
# 1.9 ms ± 68.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit wrap_list_del(arr2, 3)
# 1.05 s ± 103 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So sticking with arrays if you already have arrays (and even if you don't already have arrays, but your data is of consistent type) is about 50 times faster for small arrays and about **550 times faster for larger arrays**.
This is something to remember: Numpy arrays are there for working with numerical data! Numpy is heavily optimized for working with numerical data! There is absolutely no use in converting arrays of numerical data to another "format" if the data type (`dtype`) is constant and no super-special stuff requires it (I've barely ever encountered such a situation).
**And this is especially true for numba optimized code! Numba heavily relies on numpy and constant `dtypes`/shapes etc.  Even more if you want to work with jitclasses.**

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. That really works. But I think converting the array to a list, working on functions like del and insert() then converting back to an array is more efficient. I will upload a code snippet as soon as I can.

Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. But I can assure you that converting an array back-and-forth will **definetely be slower** than sticking with arrays. Especially for larger arrays, **converting back-and-forth will be many times slower**. There is a reason why modules like numpy exist for working with consistent types of numerical data. And this reason ist: Memory efficiency and performance for working with this kind of data! Thus converting back-and-forth would be a bad idea, if your data is already in numpy format.

Comment: Furthermore numba got some trouble working with lists of lists/arrays etc. Most python functions already work for data like this, but `del` is among the functions, that do not yet work (and probably never will?).

Comment: Thanks Scotty1, that really helps. I will consider all these constraints from now on.

Comment: You are welcome! Numba is increasing the number of supported functions/arguments really fast. So possibly some of the functions like np.delete or the axis keyword for np.all/any may be supported within the next weeks. But still I'd recommend to stick with numpy arrays for numerical operations. The advantages over lists are, in most cases, huge.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stacoverflow. You can simply use array slicing to select only rows that they dont have 3 in them. 
The code below is a bit elaborate to basically cover extra details for you although you can have a much shorter version with dropping unnecessary lines. The key assignment is `rows_final = [x for x in range(a.shape[0]) if x not in rows3]`

### Code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[10,11,3,13]])

ind = np.argwhere(a==3)
rows3 = ind[0]
cols3 = ind[1]

print ("Initial Array: \n", a)
print()
print("rows, cols of a==3 : ", rows3, cols3)

rows_final = [x for x in range(a.shape[0]) if x not in rows3]
a_final = a[rows_final,:]

print()
print ("Final Rows: \n", rows_final)
print ("Final Array: \n", a_final)
```

### Output:

```
Initial Array: 
 [[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [10 11  3 13]]

rows, cols of a==3 :  [0 2] [2 2]

Final Rows: 
 [1]
Final Array: 
 [[5 6 7 8]]
```

Comment: Thank you. The code worked for non GPU. But in numba, I get error:

numba.errors.LoweringError: Failed at object (object mode backend)
make_function(name=$const0.46, code=<code object <listcomp> at 0x7ff9b0f67930, file "/home/marwan/research/GA_for_VRP/GA_VRP/GA_VRP/file.py", line 16>, closure=$0.44, defaults=None)

File "research/GA_for_VRP/GA_VRP/GA_VRP/file.py", line 16:
def test():
    <source elided>

    rows_final = [x for x in range(a.shape[0]) if x not in rows3]
    ^
[1] During: lowering "$0.47 = make_function(name=$const0.46, code=<code object <listcomp> at 0x7ff9b0f67930

Comment: @MarwanAbdelatti, I don't have the numba setup to test, but from the documentation it says it supports the list comprehensions (See https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html). I suggest you first try the rows_final = [x for x in range(a.shape[0])] without the if and see if that works. Also the questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118734/how-to-operate-on-list-generator-using-numba) might be useful to work around your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy delete is now supported in numba (but only first to arguments being array itself and arrays containing indexes that should be deleted)

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to assign your deletion to variable a again, this worked for me. Try the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
print(a)
i = np.where(a==3)
a=np.delete(a, i, 0) # assign it back to the variable
print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but np.delete() is not supported in numba.